# What is the correct way to form MySQL queries in python?

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I am new to python, I come here from the land of PHP. I constructed a SQL query like this in python based on my PHP knowledge and I get warnings and errors

```
cursor_.execute("update posts set comment_count = comment_count + "+str(cursor_.rowcount)+" where ID = " + str(postid))
# rowcount here is int
```

What is the right way to form queries?

Also, how do I escape strings to form SQL safe ones? like if I want to escape -, ', " etc, I used to use addslashes. How do we do it in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's high time to learn to pass variables to the queries safely, using the method Matus expressed. Clearer,

```
tuple = (foovar, barvar)
cursor.execute("QUERY WHERE foo = ? AND bar = ?", tuple)
```

If you only need to pass one variable, you must still make it a tuple: insert comma at the end to tell Python to treat it as a one-tuple: `tuple = (onevar,)`

Your example would be of form:

```
cursor_.execute("update posts set comment_count = comment_count + ? where id = ?",
                (cursor_.rowcount, postid))
```

You can also use *named parameters* like this:

```
cursor_.execute("update posts set comment_count = comment_count + :count where id = :id",
                {"count": cursor_.rowcount, "id": postid})
```

This time the parameters aren't a tuple, but a dictionary that is formed in pairs of `"key": value`.

Comment: Can I use something like this? cursor.execute("update posts set comment_count = %s where postid = %d",cursor_.rowcount,postid)

Comment: @arbithero: y-yes, I think you can. From http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq I interpret that as a safe method as well. Where did you get that example from? I can't find `%d` anywhere.

Comment: @arbithero: added some examples about named queries if that looks better.

Answer (score 2):

from python manual:

```
t = (symbol,)

c.execute( 'select * from stocks where symbol=?', t )
```

this way you prevent SQL injection ( suppose this is the SQL safe you refer to ) and also have formatting solved